# compiling Qt 5.3.2 I get this error

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5

compiling Qt 5.3.2 in "VS2012 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt" with this configuration:

```
configure -developer-build -opensource -audio-backend -nomake examples -nomake tests -mp -confirm-license -opengl desktop -openssl-linked OPENSSL_LIBS="-lssleay32 -llibeay32" -I C:\Build-OpenSSL-VC-32\include -L C:\Build-OpenSSL-VC-32\lib -L "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib" -l Gdi32 -l User32
nmake
```

I get these link errors

```
    moc_wmfserviceplugin.cpp
    moc_mfstream.cpp
    moc_sourceresolver.cpp
    moc_mfplayerservice.cpp
    moc_mfplayersession.cpp
    moc_mfplayercontrol.cpp
    moc_mfaudioendpointcontrol.cpp
    moc_mfmetadatacontrol.cpp
    moc_mfaudioprobecontrol.cpp
    moc_mfvideoprobecontrol.cpp
    moc_evr9videowindowcontrol.cpp
    moc_mfdecoderservice.cpp
    moc_mfdecodersourcereader.cpp
    moc_mfaudiodecodercontrol.cpp
    link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /DLL /OUT:C:\Qt\5.3.2\qtbase\plugins\mediaservice\wmfengined.dll @C:\Users\JRondan\AppData\Local\Temp\nm413A.tmp
    Creating library C:\Qt\5.3.2\qtbase\plugins\mediaservice\wmfengined.lib and o bject C:\Qt\5.3.2\qtbase\plugins\mediaservice\wmfengined.exp
    mftvideo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MFVideoFormat_I420
    mfvideorenderercontrol.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MFVideoFormat_I420
    mfmetadatacontrol.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MFVideoFormat_M4S2
    mfmetadatacontrol.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MFVideoFormat_MP4V
    mfmetadatacontrol.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MFVideoFormat_WVC1
    mfmetadatacontrol.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MFVideoFormat_DVHD
    mfmetadatacontrol.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MFVideoFormat_DVC
    mfmetadatacontrol.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MFVideoFormat_H264
    mfmetadatacontrol.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MFVideoFormat_MJPG
    mfmetadatacontrol.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MFAudioFormat_AAC
    mfmetadatacontrol.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MFAudioFormat_ADTS
    mfdecodersourcereader.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IMFSourceReaderCallback
    C:\Qt\5.3.2\qtbase\plugins\mediaservice\wmfengined.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 11 unresolved externals
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'Stop.
```

I think I need some dll's to solve it.
How do I solve it?

Comment: That seems like a pretty old Windows SDK version to be using with VS2012, no?

Answer (score 0):

I updade to Windows SDK 7.1 and change on my configure option and its work :D,

```
configure -developer-build -opensource -audio-backend -nomake examples -nomake tests -mp -confirm-license -opengl desktop -openssl-linked OPENSSL_LIBS="-lssleay32 -llibeay32" -I C:\Build-OpenSSL-VC-32\include -L C:\Build-OpenSSL-VC-32\lib -L "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib" -l Gdi32 -l User32
```

thank a lot @Cameron